# `stack ghci` without threads? OpenGL stutters in GHCI

Tags: multithreading, opengl, ffi, ghci

I'm developing an application that uses OpenGL to render an image. My usual workflow involves testing code in GHCI, as `:r` reloading and interpreted mode are much faster than compiling.

When I run the code from ghci via Stack (`stack ghci`), the frontend stutters and may not respond to input events.

If I compile the code without `-threaded`, it works as expected.

I can also make it work from `stack ghci` using `runInBoundThread`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer turned out to be passing the correct RTS option to ghci:

```
stack repl --ghci-options='+RTS -N -RTS'
```